# PHP: Modify value of multidimensional array using foreach

Tags: php, arrays, excel, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have a project using **Yii2**, in my project the user can upload an excel file,  and the system read the data and set it into a new two dimensional array, for example:

#### Example.xls

[image]

An this is the code that I've used in my **Controller**:

```
 for ($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
            $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
            if (!is_null($rowData[0][0])) {
                    foreach ($rowData as $key => $value) {
                        foreach ($value as $vKey => $vValue) {
                            $tempArrayData[] = $vKey . "_" . $vValue;
                        }
                }
                $arrayData[] = $tempArrayData;
            }
}
 echo '<pre>';
 print_r($arrayData);
 echo '</pre>';
 die();
```

I want to add `"$key_"` as two first character in each array's values.
So I use *foreach* to do that, and I've got this as the **result**:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
        [0] => 0_first_name
        [1] => 1_last_name
        [2] => 2_age
        [3] => 3_sex
      )
  [1] => Array
      (
        [0] => 0_first_name
        [1] => 1_last_name
        [2] => 2_age
        [3] => 3_sex
        [4] => 0_Archie
        [5] => 1_Will
        [6] => 2_21
        [7] => 3_Male
      )  
  [2] => Array
      (
        [0] => 0_first_name
        [1] => 1_last_name
        [2] => 2_age
        [3] => 3_sex
        [4] => 0_Archie
        [5] => 1_Will
        [6] => 2_21
        [7] => 3_Male
        [8] => 0_Vani
        [9] => 1_Priscillia
        [10] => 2_21
        [11] => 3_Female
      )
)
```

But that's not what I've expected, in the result above the  array of array always start from first column of Excel data. Actually, I need a result like this:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
        [0] => 0_first_name
        [1] => 1_last_name
        [2] => 2_age
        [3] => 3_sex
      )
  [1] => Array
      (
        [0] => 0_Archie
        [1] => 1_Will
        [2] => 2_21
        [3] => 3_Male
      )  
  [2] => Array
      (
        [0] => 0_Vani
        [1] => 1_Priscillia
        [2] => 2_21
        [3] => 3_Female
      )
)
```

This is the example result that I need, anyone know how to get result like above? or how can I modify my code in above so I can get result as I've expect. Thanks.

### Edited

If I remove this `foreach ($value as $vKey => $vValue) {`, and `print_r($value)` inside `foreach ($rowData as $key => $value) {`, it has result like this:

```
Array
(
[0] => first_name
[1] => last_name
[2] => age
[3] => sex
)
Array
(
[0] => Archie
[1] => Will
[2] => 21
[3] => Male
)  
Array
(
[0] => Vani
[1] => Priscillia
[2] => 21
[3] => Female
)
```

### Final array result

```
Array
(
 [0] => Array
    (
     [0] => Array
        (
          [0] => 0_first_name
          [1] => 1_last_name
          [2] => 2_age
          [3] => 3_sex
        )
    )
)

 [1] => Array
    (
     [0] => Array
        (
          [0] => 0_Archie
          [1] => 1_Will
          [2] => 2_21
          [3] => 3_Male
        )  
    )

 [2] => Array
    (
     [0] => Array
        (
          [0] => 0_Vani
          [1] => 1_Priscillia
          [2] => 2_21
          [3] => 3_Female
        ) 
    )    
)
```

## Final Code that solved this case:

```
 $arrayData = [];
for($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
  $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

  $arrayData[] = array_map(function($values) {
if (!is_null($rowData[0][0])) {
    $tempArrayData = [];
    foreach($values as $key => $value) {
      $tempArrayData[] = $key . '_' . $value;
    }
    return $tempArrayData;
  }, $rowData);
    }
    }
```

## UPDATE

**the project has an update requierment, the project has been successfully create result as *Final Result* above. But now the array need a modify, the expected result is like this**:

```
Array
(
  [0] => Array
    (
     [0] => Array
        (
          [0] => 0_first_name
          [1] => 1_last_name
          [2] => 2_age
          [3] => 3_sex
        )
     )
  [1] => Array
    (
     [0] => Array
        (
          [0] => 0_Archie
          [1] => 1_Will
          [2] => 2_21
          [3] => 3_Male
        )  
    )
  [2] => Array
    (
     [0] => Array
        (
          [0] => 0_Vani
          [1] => 1_Priscillia
          [2] => 2_21
          [3] => 3_Female
        ) 
    )    
)
```

Anyone know how to solve this? Thanks

Comment: Can you do `print_r($rowData)` and add it so we know what we can work on?

Comment: maybe you need to remove this `foreach ($value as $vKey => $vValue) {` and check what is in `foreach ($rowData as $key => $value) {' by using print_r($value) or as @Archibald say.

Comment: @prateekkathal if I do `print_r($rowData)`, it will only print the value from first column of uploaded Excel file. So in this case, it will print out `Array
(
  [0] => Array
      (
        [0] => 0_first_name
        [1] => 1_last_name
        [2] => 2_age
        [3] => 3_sex
      )
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do this

```
$rowData = [];

for($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
  $rowData[] = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);
}
```

Now your `$rowData` should be equal to

```
$rowData = [
  ["first_name", "last_name", "age", "sex"],
  ["Archie", "Will", "21", "Male"],
  ["Vani", "Priscillia", "21", "Female"]
];
```

You can simply try doing this

```
$arrayData[] = array_map(function($values) {
  $tempArrayData = [];
  foreach($values as $key => $value) {
    $tempArrayData[] = $key . '_' . $value;
  }
  return $tempArrayData;
}, $rowData);
```

### Final Code

```
$arrayData = [];

for($row = 1; $row <= $highestRow; ++$row) {
  $rowData = $sheet->rangeToArray('A' . $row . ':' . $highestColumn . $row, NULL, TRUE, FALSE);

  $arrayData[][0] = array_map(function($values) {
    $tempArrayData = [];
    foreach($values as $key => $value) {
      $tempArrayData[] = $key . '_' . $value;
    }
    return $tempArrayData;
  }, $rowData);
}
```

### Final Output

```
array:3 [▼
  0 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "0_first_name"
    1 => "1_last_name"
    2 => "2_age"
    3 => "3_sex"
  ]
  1 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "0_Archie"
    1 => "1_Will"
    2 => "2_21"
    3 => "3_Male"
  ]
  2 => array:4 [▼
    0 => "0_Vani"
    1 => "1_Priscillia"
    2 => "2_21"
    3 => "3_Female"
  ]
]
```

Comment: I'm not sure if my array is equal to that one, but I'm sure both of that arrays have same array type (2 dimensional array). I've tried your code, but the code only get the value from last column. So the result the I've got was `Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 0_Vani
            [1] => 1_Priscillia
            [2] => 2_21
            [3] => 3_Female
    )
)

Comment: @Archibald Then what is `$rowData` equal to? Please edit your question and paste the array.

Comment: hi @prateekkathal, I've edit my question, and I've add array and I think my array equal to yours.

Comment: @Archibald Did you check my updated answer? It should definitely work.... Try the **Final Code** section.

Comment: Yah, I'm trying your code right now, but It has an _Array to string conversion_ error in `$tempArrayData[] = $key . '_' . $value;`

Comment: @Archibald Try now.

Comment: Yeah thankyou @prateekkathal, finally your code solve my problem :). But the _array_ result become three dimensional _array_, and It also print an empty array. You can check the result in my edited question.

Comment: halo @prateekkathal, the array need a modify. Wish you can give a help again. I've been add the requierment above in **Update** label. Thanks

Comment: @Archibald Just add `[0]` after `$arrayData[]`... Updated the answer... Check.

Comment: I've tried your suggestion, but it didn't work. That code make the array become four dimensional array.